# How to fill DataGridView on wcf callback operation

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, callback

I have tried to fill datagridview using wcf callback operation on button click but on first click wcf returns null value & when i click the button second time it fetch the data & fill the gridview data.

**Below is my WCF service....**

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, CallbackContract =typeof(IServiceCallback))]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
        void GetData(string userName,string password);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Callback Interface
    /// </summary>
    public interface IServiceCallback
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
        void SendResult(Department[] arrDept);
    }


    [DataContract]
    public class Department
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int DeptNo { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string DeptName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Capacity { get; set; }
    }


[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
    public class Service : IService
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Get a channel instance that is used to called the current operation 
        /// </summary>
        public IServiceCallback CallBack
        {
            get 
            {
                return OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IServiceCallback>(); 
            }
        }

        public void GetData(string userName, string password)
        {
            Department[] arrDept = new Department[]
            {
                 new Department() {DeptNo=10,DeptName="IT",Capacity=4500},
                 new Department() {DeptNo=20,DeptName="HRD",Capacity=200},
                 new Department() {DeptNo=30,DeptName="ACCTS",Capacity=40}
            };

            if (userName.Trim() == "mahesh" && password == "mahesh")
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10000); 
                CallBack.SendResult(arrDept);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Web.Config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Service"
        name="WCF_CallBack_Service.Service">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" 
                  contract="WCF_CallBack_Service.IService">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" 
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Service">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Client Call...**

```
public class RequestCallBack : IServiceCallback
    {
        private Department[] _Departments;

        public Department[] Departments
        {
            get { return _Departments; }
            set 
            {
                _Departments = value;
            }
        }
        public void SendResult(Department[] arrDept)
        {
            Departments = arrDept;
            MessageBox.Show("Response  Received " + Departments.Count().ToString() );

        }


    }


public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        MyRef.ServiceClient Proxy;
        RequestCallBack callback;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnGetData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Proxy.GetData("mahesh", "mahesh");
           MessageBox.Show("Values are send to the service");
          dgvDept.DataSource = callback.Departments; 

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            callback = new RequestCallBack(); 
            //Get the InstanceContext with the help of the CallBack contract class
            InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(callback);
            Proxy = new MyRef.ServiceClient(context);
        }
    }
```

**client app.config..**

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsDualHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_IService" />
            </wsDualHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:4221/Service.svc" binding="wsDualHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_IService" contract="MyRef.IService"
                name="WSDualHttpBinding_IService">
                <identity>
                    <userPrincipalName value="MY-PC\MY PC" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're looking for a few lines of code that will make it all magically work, but I don't think you'll find that. I can tell you how I use WCF to update my DataGridView.

So I have a controller program where the grid exists, and the grid is used to display the status of a set of emulators that load test software. So when I start my controller and the load test, this is what follows:

The controller uses a WCF call (wshttpbinding) to call the Start() route on the emulator, which has a return value of an object

```
public void Start(IProgress<EmulatorStatus> progress)
{
}
```

On the Emulator side, every time a routine is finished by the emulator, it uses Progress.Report(EmulatorStatus) to send back to the Controller the object (containing text, numbers, booleans) describing the status of the emulation.

On the client side, the Controller is looping every 10 seconds, checking for status updates from the Emulator host.

```
while ((this.m_DoHeartBeatLoop)) {

   //update grid
   if (StatusChange) {
       DataGridView.DataSource = new List<EmulatorStatus>();
   }

   //Sleep between each WatchDog Loop
   Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```

I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for, but it's what I'm using. Best of luck.